# How to access the files in Azure NetApp?

Tags: azure, azure-files, azure-storage-files, netapp, azure-storage-explorer

I am wondering if the Azure Storage explorer can be used to access the files in *Azure NetApp*. If not, what is the storage explorer-like solution for *Azure NetApp*?

Answer (score 0):

No storage explorer [cannot be used to access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-netapp-files/azure-netapp-files-faqs#can-i-manage-azure-netapp-files-through-azure-storage-explorer) NetApp files. I highly doubt if there is an explorer available as of now unless you use some commands and create your own onw